# Well defineness of the definition of F1 score

Tags: classification, model-evaluation, definition

The F1 score is defined as the harmonic mean of precision and recall:

$$ F_{1}=2\cdot {\frac {\mathrm {precision} \cdot \mathrm {recall} }{\mathrm {precision} +\mathrm {recall} }}.$$

The above formula can be rewritten in terms of TP, FP and FN as

$$ F_{1}= \frac{2TP}{2TP+FP+FN}.$$

precision exists if and only if $TP+FP>0$, and recall exists if and only if $TP+FN>0$.

When $TP=FP=0$ and $FN>0$, precision doesn't exist and recall does. According to the first formula, $F_1$ isn't well defined, while according to the second formula if it were the definition of $F_1$, $F_1$ is well defined and is $0$. 
Should $F_1$ be considered to exist or not?